# Tidy up output from combined command

Tags: powershell

I am trying to tidy up the output of a command. Command is:

```
Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(name=comput*)" -searchbase "ou=xx,dc=xx,dc=local" | 
Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf Group_name -passthru
```

I have used "Start-Transcript" to output to a file. But, each file gives:

```
DistinguishedName : CN=Computer1,OU=xx,DC=xx,DC=LOCAL
Name              : Computer1
ObjectClass       : computer
ObjectGUID        : 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
SamAccountName    : Computer1$
SID               : S-1-5-21-1111111111-111111111-1111111111-111111
```

I'd ideally just like a list of "Name" from the command.

Also, if possible can we change the start/stop-transcript to give a better date format than "End time: 20191010163001"

Ideally I'd just like to output to a CSV instead so I can have the list in columns and just filter out what I don't need if it's easier. I don't know if I can use export-file instead to get a CSV?

Comment: Are you just trying to get all the AD Group Memberships of all the computers in a certain OU?

Comment: No. I want to add an AD security group to all users in an OU. I want to pipe out the result, but only the computer name, and not the full details as above. Ideally in CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to excuse me, I've just figured out how to use Classes in PowerShell and I'm purposely making my life harder to include them in everything :-)

You could create a class to hold the information that you wanted (e.g "ComputerName", "GroupName" and "TimeStamp"), create a `Foreach-Object` look when using `Get-ADComputer`, perform your actions, create a new instance of the class, add the instance to the list and then output the list to a CSV when finished. I'm going to stop rambling now, here is what I would use:

```
#Create a new class to hold the info for our CSV entry
Class CSVEntry{
    [String]$ComputerName
    [String]$GroupName
    [String]$TimeStamp
}

#Creating a list to hold the CSV entries
$Results = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]'

#Defined the name of the group here
$groupName = 'Group_Name'

Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(name=comput*)" -searchbase "ou=xx,dc=xx,dc=local" | ForEach-Object{

    #Add the computer to the group here
    Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf $groupName -Identity $_

    #Build a custom CSVEntry object and add it to the list
    $newRecord = [CSVEntry]::new()
    $newRecord.ComputerName = $_.Name
    $newRecord.GroupName = $groupName
    $newRecord.TimeStamp = Get-Date

    #Add the new record to the list
    $Results.Add($newRecord)
}

#Export the list of CSV entries
$Results | Export-Csv C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.csv
```

Is it overbaked, maybe... but I hope it helps you :)

Comment: That is completely new to me. But. It excited me! I'll give this a tweak and a play tomorrow and come back at you with how it runs! Thankyou :)

Comment: As a cheeky side question, I see that will run and run silently and output to a file. Just so I can see it working in case I add 10,000 users to a group, how would I output to screen the machine it currently is adding? I appreciate it'll be in the CSV also but it's more to see it run.

Comment: You could add a `Write-Host $_.Name - $groupName` to the area where the `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` so that you can see the current computer and the group

Comment: Damn it works beautifully! 
I tried to modify it for users added into an AD group and failed miserably. I'll post new! :)