# Add users into AD group with correct CSV output

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add an AD group into user profiles based on an OU

I had a similar script working, so tried to modify it and failed. I am guessing it's the " -Identity $_" it maybe, but I am not good enough to debug.

```
#Create a new class to hold the info for our CSV entry
Class CSVEntry{
    [String]$UserName
    [String]$GroupName
    [String]$TimeStamp
}

#Creating a list to hold the CSV entries
$Results = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]'

#Defined the name of the group here
$GroupName = 'GROUPS NAME'
$ou = 'ou=XX,ou=XX,ou=XX,dc=XX,dc=local'

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $ou | ForEach-Object{

    #Add the user to the group here
    Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf $GroupName Identity $_

    #Write-Host $_.Name - $groupName 

    #Build a custom CSVEntry object and add it to the list
    $newRecord = [CSVEntry]::new()
    $newRecord.UserName = $_.Name
    $newRecord.GroupName = $groupName
    $newRecord.TimeStamp = Get-Date

    #Add the new record to the list
    $Results.Add($newRecord)
}


#Export the list of CSV entries
$Results | Export-Csv C:\PS\AddADGroupToUsers.csv
```

errors:

```
Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'CN=NAME,OU=XX,OU=XX,OU=XX,OU=XX,DC=XX,DC=LOCAL'.
At line:18 char:5
+     Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf $GroupName Identity $_
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADPrincipal
   GroupMembership
```

EDIT:
So, the script doesn't actually do any changes, the group doesn't get added to the users. the output on screen is:

```
WARNING: User  is already a member of group XYZ
WARNING: User  is already a member of group XYZ
WARNING: User  is already a member of group XYZ

UserName GroupName                          TimeStamp
-------- ---------                          ---------
shows ok       XYZ        14/10/2019 14:50:23
shows ok       XYZ        14/10/2019 14:50:23
shows ok       XYZ        14/10/2019 14:50:23
```

All I have changed is the group name to XYZ and username shows ok in the second half. But, shows blank in the top, and I assure you that a) the user isn't already in the group and b) the script isn't adding them

Current tweaked code, warts and all but sanitised:

```
$groupName = 'GROUP'
$ou = 'setcorrectly'
$cred = Get-Credential -credential dom\usr

$results = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $ou -Credential $cred | ForEach-Object {
    #Add the user to the group here
    try {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupName -Members $_.DistinguishedName -Credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "User $($_.Name) is already a member of group $groupName"
    } 

        # output a PsCustomObject that gets collected in the $results variable
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            'UserName'  = $_.Name
            'GroupName' = $groupName
            'TimeStamp' = Get-Date
}
}

# output on console
$results | Format-Table -AutoSize

# Export to CSV file
$results | Export-Csv C:\PS\AddADGroupToUsers.csv -NoTypeInformation

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

CSV output shows the second half of the screen output only, and doesn't say anything is already a member

Comment: `-MemberOf` is not a parameter of `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`. What is the goal of what you were trying there?

Comment: I was trying to re-use the commands from another question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58326448/tidy-up-output-from-combined-command/58327068?noredirect=1#comment103030503_58327068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below uses `Add-ADGroupMember` to add user(s) to 1 group instead of `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` which is used to add 1 user to multiple groups.

It also uses `[PsCustomObject]`s to output the results, so you don't need to use the Class CSVEntry.

```
# Define the name of the group here.
# can be either:
# A distinguished name
# A GUID (objectGUID)
# A security identifier (objectSid)
# A Security Account Manager account name (sAMAccountName)
$groupName = '<NAME OF THE GROUP>'

$ou = 'ou=XX,ou=XX,ou=XX,dc=XX,dc=local'

$results = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $ou | ForEach-Object {
    #Add the user to the group here
    $userName = $_.Name
    try {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupName -Members $_.DistinghuishedName -ErrorAction Stop
        # output a PsCustomObject that gets collected in the $results variable
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            'UserName'  = $_.Name
            'GroupName' = $groupName
            'TimeStamp' = Get-Date
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "User $userName is already a member of group $groupName"
    } 
}

# output on console
$results | Format-Table -AutoSize

# Export to CSV file
$results | Export-Csv C:\PS\AddADGroupToUsers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

---

**Edit**

If you want the `$results` variable to ALSO contain users that are already a member of the group, you could simply move the creation of the `[PsCustomObject]` below the `catch{..}` block:

```
$results = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $ou | ForEach-Object {
    #Add the user to the group here
    $userName = $_.Name
    try {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupName -Members $_.DistinghuishedName -ErrorAction Stop
        $status = "User added successfully"
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "User $userName is already a member of group $groupName"
        $status = "User is already a member"
    }

    # output a PsCustomObject that gets collected in the $results variable
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'UserName'  = $userName
        'GroupName' = $groupName
        'TimeStamp' = Get-Date
        'Status'    = $status
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I love your use of try and catch, wouldn't you need to use a finally command, or is that not required?

Comment: I can't edit my comment. Anyway. Shouldn't "Finally" maybe encompass the "output on console"?

Comment: Sorry, also I can't run a ps1 as my admin account. how do I get this to run/ask for my admin account details?

Comment: @RobPowell The `Finally{..}` block is not required. It is mostly used for cleaning up actions like releasing Com objects you may have used or removing temporary files and such. You should not use it here to show the "output on console". That is just a matter of if you want that output or not and you can only use after all info is collected in the $results variable.

Comment: @RobPowell Both the `Get-ADUser` and `Add-ADGroupMember` have a `Credential` parameter you could use. To have the code ask for credentials, simply put this line on top `$cred = Get-Credential -Message "Please enter your Admin credentials here"`. Then add this to the Get-ADUser and Add-ADGroupMember cmdlets: `-Credential $cred`.

Comment: thankyou so much for your help and advice @Theo it's much appeciated!

Comment: ,this doesn't quite work. The error for someone already in the group is:
"WARNING: User  is already a member of group (actual group name edited"
so it doesn't list the username. It also doesn't actually apply the group even though the users don't have the group on their account.
It errors the correct number of times for the users in the OU, so the count is working ok

Comment: @RobPowell I have edited the code to also include the users that were already member of the group. However, I don't understand what you mean by _doesn't actually apply the group even though the users don't have the group on their account_.. The code adds users to a group, that is your question isn't it?

Comment: {Theo, see edit in original post to see the exact code used, and output. In short, it shows all users as already a member when they're not, doesn't apply the group, and output to CSV just shows username, groupname, and timestamp.

Comment: @RobPowell Sorry, I forgot the `$_` automatic variable inside a catch block is in fact the exception that occurred, no longer the user object from the ForEach-Object loop. Changed that now. Also, please check and **refresh** ADUC to see if the users were added to the group.

Comment: ok, progress. I removed the "-credential $cred" from the Add-ADGroupMember command, and then it reported back correctly! It outputs on the screen in 2 lists as you've seen, but the CSV is only containing the second half. Is there any PS magic we can do to maybe add a column like "already a member" or "succeed" or something to show what has been added, and what was already there? Moving the PSCustomObject captures everything but only lists name, group, and time. It doesn't clarify anything. If this is too much then I am happy where we are now :D

Comment: @RobPowell I have added a status column.